# Can google vision api be used to achieve Optical Mark Recognition?

Tags: python, google-vision

So I was thinking of using google automl for training on identifying ticked boxes and then find a way to manipulate it to suit my needs. I would like some directions on how to use the api to achieve omr on survey forms.

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve OMR with Google Vision ?

Comment: Nope. Google Vision API is only suited for OCR.